# How to wait user confirm on another browser / mobile device to allow continue

Tags: python, input, async-await, celery

I'm struggling to find the right way to ask.

I want to build those interaction that the user try to login for example.
Them the system say that he need to confirm (on email or on another device) and after user confirm the page automatically reload.

I know that for sure need to use ajax on the front end.

But in the backend using python not sure? Should I create a unique task for that and listen to that task? Queue?

Any idea what I should use? Celery? Redis?

Comment: It depends on how your user model was designed. What happens when user confirms? And how it happens? Throw a link sent on email? I don't think Celery is necessary here. A simple ajax pool from the frontend to a api route on your backend to check if user has confirmed shall be enough.

Comment: Yep basically when user confirm the page that was waiting should automatically reload and continue without need user refresh

Comment: I would go with a simple ajax request, token protected - e.g. JWT -, pooling every 3 minutes a route on your python backend designed to check if user has confirmed... if so, it redirects to the next page.